# Can boost lib built on windows with msvc be used in a linux program

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, cmake

I built boost from source on windows. I can compile with it on windows.

When I want to compile with it in linux :

> Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.65.1
>
> Boost include path: pathtoproject/deps/boost
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_system
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
>   to the   directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the
>   location of   Boost.

So I set findboost debug flag to understand why using

```
 set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
```

in CMake. I get :

> Boost_FOUND = 1

But also

> Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc54-mt-1_65_1;boost_system-gcc54-mt;boost_system-mt-1_65_1;boost_system-mt;boost_system

Which means cmake is looking for libs named "*gcc54*".

But my libs are named "*vc141*" (msvc).

So can it works or do I need 2 boost builds for it to work on both systems.

Comment: ***Can boost lib built on windows with msvc be used in a linux program*** Not really. May be somewhat possible using wine but I would just recompile on linux instead.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you. The only clean solution is building boost again on linux ?

Comment: Yes, And since you are already using CMake for your code, the process should be simpler.

Comment: Note that building boost on linux will typically produce files that can be safely used only on that particular linux flavor. So it might be necessary to build it over and over again for each linux distributive that you want to support. Or you can utilize some precompiled boost installed using system package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't mix and match between compilers, unless it is explicitly supported. In this case, it is very much not supported.

Comment: Even if you had the same version of gcc on Windows and gcc on Linux, you can't mix and match the resulting binaries between operating systems.